# How to remove toolbar shadow in Android?

Tags: android, xml

Hi I am developing an app and I want to remove toolbar shadow, I tried adding `app:elevation="0dp"` to AppBarLayout but after adding this the menu button for opening navigationView does not work,Any idea?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private SlidingMenuLayout slidingMenuLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    slidingMenuLayout = (SlidingMenuLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, null);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(slidingMenuLayout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.notifications);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.open_drawer:
            toggleMenu();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void toggleMenu() {
    slidingMenuLayout.toggleMenu();
 } }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<net.aparteman.apartemanapp.viewHolder.SlidingMenuLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/dark_purple"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/dashboard_nav_header"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/dashboard_drawer_view"
    app:theme="@style/ApartemanStyle" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As elevation also affects the `View`'s z-index, I guess what's happening is that your `FrameLayout` is above the `Toolbar`, eating the touch events.

Try to either put the `FrameLayout` before the `AppBarLayout` in the XML, or define your `FrameLayout` with a top margin to leave room to the `Toolbar`.

Comment: Thank you It was the problem I put the FrameLayout before the AppBarLayout